# Jenkins Pipeline: how to retrieve variables defined in my previous Builds

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am a beginner with jenkins, and I would like to know how to get the variables(Not environment Var) defined in my previous builds to use them in the current build enter code here

Comment: Check out the [Rebuilder Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/rebuild/) it enables you to rebuild any build you choose with the original execution parameters, while still allowing you to edit the original values.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is by using artifacts.  You can archive the data you want in the upstream build as an artifact, then copy that artifact in the downstream build.

## 1. Archive the artifact in the upstream pipeline

`archiveArtifacts output.json`

## 2 Copy the artifact in the downstream pipeline

```
copyArtifacts projectName: upstreamJobName,
        filter: 'output.json',
        // selector: // "last stable" is selected by not providing this parameter
        fingerprintArtifacts: true,
        flatten: true

def output = readJSON(file: 'output.json')
```

You will need to install the [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/copyartifact/).